# Facebook C# SDK mapping places to a model

Tags: c#, json, facebook-c#-sdk

[Here](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAP1aZAvXPvUyHkIHDNdHyV4NaLcYVtrWswilUBNllblVfvqCUEan5tZBdck1uu1upknTYcU5BD5XvOfdK4pyuE3ECzlXRKxYfIDKQZA) is an example of a result , ( facebook public exmaple )

(/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000)

I have this model :

```
[DataContract]
public class FBPlaces
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public List<Place> Data { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "paging")]
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Paging
{
    [DataMember(Name = "next")]
    public string Next { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Place
{
    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Location
{
    [DataMember(Name = "street")]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "state")]
    public string State { get; set; }

    //[DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "country ")]
    //public string Country { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "zip")]
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "longitude")]
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

the problem is mapping "location" array , I get

System.ArgumentException: Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Void set_Item(Int32, MyProject.Models.Location)'

- If I remove Locations , everything is fine , I get the Catergory+Name+Id . ( but no  locations )
- How to fix it?
- In my real example (different location query),"country" isn't always shown, How I deal with this kind of data? I commented Country property .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location isn't an array within place.

Try

```
[DataContract]
 public class Place
 {
    [DataMember(Name = "location")]
    public Location Locations { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "category")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks  ( thanks also to the other answer which was the same idea , but was deleted :) )